# Values of labels for sklearn binary classifiers

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification

I have the dataset with samples labeled as "0" or "1".

Should the labels be "-1" and "1" for correct classification?

I am not sure what loss functions sklearn classifiers minimize. Maybe it relies on the values to be either "1" or "-1"?

Answer (score 1):

`sklearn` classifiers can usually use different loss functions or penalties. All though I cannot find this documented anywhere, in my experience, it is usually smart about the classes you pass in. The actual solvers use external libraries, so under the hood there is likely some sanitization that occurs. But generally, I find these work out of the box:

```
>>> from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
>>> import numpy as np
>>> X = np.random.randint(0,10,(20,5))
>>> y1 = np.random.choice([-1,1], 20)
>>> y2 = np.random.choice([0,1], 20)
>>> y1
array([-1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,
        1, -1,  1])
>>> y2
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
>>> model1, model2 = LogisticRegression(), LogisticRegression()
>>> model1.fit(X,y1)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> model2.fit(X, y2)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> model1.predict(X)
array([-1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1, -1,
        1, -1,  1])
>>> model2.predict(X)
array([1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0])
>>> y1
array([-1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1,  1, -1,  1,  1, -1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,
        1, -1,  1])
>>> y2
array([0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0])
```

Or even:

```
>>> y3 = np.random.choice(['a','b'], 20)
>>> model3 = LogisticRegression()
>>> model3.fit(X,y3)
LogisticRegression(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
          intercept_scaling=1, max_iter=100, multi_class='ovr', n_jobs=1,
          penalty='l2', random_state=None, solver='liblinear', tol=0.0001,
          verbose=0, warm_start=False)
>>> model3.classes_
array(['a', 'b'],
      dtype='<U1')
>>> model3.predict(X)
array(['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'b', 'b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Or, using Support Vector Machines:

```
>>> from sklearn.svm import LinearSVC
>>> svm1 = LinearSVC()
>>> svm1.fit(X,y1)
LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
     intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
     multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
     verbose=0)
>>> svm1.predict(X)
array([-1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1, -1, -1,  1,  1,  1, -1, -1, -1,  1,
        1, -1,  1])
>>> svm2 = LinearSVC()
>>> svm2.fit(X,y3)
LinearSVC(C=1.0, class_weight=None, dual=True, fit_intercept=True,
     intercept_scaling=1, loss='squared_hinge', max_iter=1000,
     multi_class='ovr', penalty='l2', random_state=None, tol=0.0001,
     verbose=0)
>>> svm2.predict(X)
array(['b', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a',
       'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a', 'a'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

Just always read the documentation of your classifier, and I think that if it were the case that it only accepts a specific type of labelling scheme, it would be documented.